# Python Kivy Error: [CRITICAL] [App ] Unable to get a Window, abort

Tags: python, python-3.x, window, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to run some simple code in Kivy. Could someone please help? **Note:** I have two hard drives installed on my PC, and I am not sure if this could have an effect with the paths. I am new to this. Please have mercy on me! Thank you so much in advance.

**This is the code that I am trying to run:**

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class SimpleKivy(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Hello World!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SimpleKivy().run()
```

---

**Here is the error I am receiving:**

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Gamer\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-06-25_14.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 07:18:10) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider.
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
  File "E:\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "E:\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 26, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
 Exception ignored in: 'kivy.properties.dpi2px'
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "E:\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\utils.py", line 496, in __get__
     retval = self.func(inst)
   File "E:\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\metrics.py", line 174, in dpi
     EventLoop.ensure_window()
   File "E:\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 127, in ensure_window
     sys.exit(1)
 SystemExit: 1
[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Comment: This is an already asked question, please search for the old solutions.

Comment: So you are starting to learn kivy?

Comment: I have searched for the old solutions and couldn't find one that worked. Yes, I am starting to learn kivy

Comment: Same here.  I  also started learning kivy from yesterday. I too got this problem but now it is solved.

Comment: How did you fix this?

Comment: Some how i followed the old solutions and i got recovered from this problem.

Comment: Are you installing in windows or linux?

Comment: I found a solution! I had to update pip and install a few extra things. I followed the instructions on this link https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#installation

Comment: Yeah superb!!!!

Comment: Now start your programming